# Trigger onEdit() with a programmatic edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that takes data from one sheet when it is edited and puts that recently added data into ScriptDb.

The `onEdit()` trigger is fired successfully when I actually open the sheet and make an edit.

However, this sheet is edited programmatically through a script. Is `onEdit()` able to fire based on edits made by a script? I have not been able to make it do so.

The script that is fired with the `onEdit()` trigger is:

```
function sheetWasEdited(event) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastRowValues = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2, 1, 2).getValues()[0];
  CgcEmailDatabase.addEmail(now=lastRowValues[0].toString(), email=lastRowValues[1].toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onEdit trigger is intended to work when an actual user edits a spreadsheet, the use case you describe should be easy to implement simply by calling your `sheetWasEdited()` function from the other function if the latest is part of the same project.

If the changes are made from another project (another spreadsheet or a web app) then it will become quite harder to put in place. (let us know if it is your use case)

---

EDIT following your comments :

The idea is to monitor the length of the sheet, keep the value somewhere (in script properties for example) and call your function if a row has been added.

This small code should do the trick, you should set a time trigger to call `lookatsheet()` once in a while, depending on how fast you need to react... I'd say every hour or 30' shouldn't be too much, you decide.

```
function lookatsheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');// the ID of the SS you want to look at
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];// first sheet
  var lastrow = sh.getLastRow();
  var formertest = ScriptProperties.getProperty('lastTest');// recover the value from the last test (will need to get called once to initiate a valid value)
  if (formertest < lastrow){
    sheetWasEdited(lastrow);// call your function with lastRow as parameter
    ScriptProperties.setProperties({'lastTest': lastrow}, true);   // store for next time
}
}

function sheetWasEdited(row) {  // modified to work with the other function
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx').getSheets()[0]
  var lastRowValues = sheet.getRange(row, 2, 1, 2).getValues()[0];
  CgcEmailDatabase.addEmail(now=lastRowValues[0].toString(), email=lastRowValues[1].toString());
}
```

**NOTE:** *may be useful to comment the mail call on the first run to avoid sending a mail ( just to initiate the script properties)*

Comment: Unfortunately I don't own the sheet with the function that programmatically does the edit, so I can't have it call the sheetWasEdited() function. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just a few questions:how complicated is the spreadsheet?Does is have multiple sheets?  Do the changes add data or modify data? Are data just variables or formulas as well and are these subject to change also?

Comment: The spreadsheet is very simple with just one sheet. The changes only add data (ie. adds a row). The data are just text and not formulas, and the data do not change.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the time-based trigger will not work because these changes to ScriptDb must be done in real time.

What I am maintaining in ScriptDb is an email subscription list. I have one form for subscribing and another form for unsubscribing. 

The subscription form is the one that I don't own and is the one that makes the programmatic edits. I own the unsubscribe form.

If the writes to ScriptDb are done in batches, the subscribe status may not match up. ie. if you subscribe, then unsubscribe, and subscribe again.