# Running Google spreadsheet script from a different spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have several spreadsheets that collect data from multiple/different forms and I can run a script bound to that spreadsheet based on form submit.
However, what I would like to do is to have the script of the form spreadsheet access and run the script of a main spreadsheet.
The main spreadsheet collects and processes data from several different forms.
It seems that using a trigger in the main spreadsheet based onEdit only applies when a user is actually editing, not when another spreadsheet writes data to it.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164736/trigger-onedit-with-a-programmatic-edit). It seems

> OnEdit trigger is intended to work when an actual user edits a spreadsheet

If each of these other sheets is just adding a row to the main sheet, you can create a way that the main sheet keeps track of how many rows it knows are there. Then you set up a cron that runs every X minutes, checks if there are new rows, and does what it needs to on those.

Comment: Thanks Phil.  Yes, I have set up a clock based trigger in the main spreadsheet and have an algorithm for it to track updates to the form driven spreadsheets. I may end up going down that path, but was trying for a cleaner solution.

Comment: Another idea I had was to have the form sheets inside the main spreadsheet, but a spreadsheet can only have a single form writing to it. Larry

Comment: Sadly, it seems that it's just not possible. And I don't understand why. From my experience, if a script edits a spreadsheet, it triggers onEdit. It must be that in your case, it's a separate spreadsheet doing the editing.