# Trying to make a script that scans a Google Sheet and emails if values are below 60%

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I searched and tried to use what I could find, but I'm stuck.  I am attempting to create a script that scans a Google sheet (with about 30 sheets) for  values that are **newly inputted** and are below 60%.  I am then looking to have the script e-mail me the data that is in the 2nd column (Student's name), 4th column (teacher's name) of the current row of the data as well as the percentage (test score)that was below 60% (ex. Clarke,John   Mrs. Brown  56.64%) .  I am new to Java script but have been trying to learn.

Here is the script that I have so far.  It finds the correct sheet without a problem.  It will also email me as well (with the wrong message, but it works none the less).  But there are certain things that I am stuck on.  Like I know that I have to set up some sort of onEdit trigger so that it only sends the newly inputted score, but I don't know where to put it or how to do that.  I also know that the dataRange code that I have seems wrong to me and the if statement also seems wrong.  I am not sure how to specify "below 60%".
I am a technology teacher and set up a massive data system for our school using Google Drive.  I want to have the master data sheet automatically email my principal whenever a student needs help on a specific assessment.  Any help you could give me would be much appreciated!
Thank you guys so much for all of your time  I love spending my time on here learning from everyone.
Brandon

[Here is a link to an example of the data spreadsheet we use](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CvK-ALbc-_GZwX4pqadBb67AVAou6euk55OE1axfbAk/edit?usp=sharing)

Choppy Script Below

```js
function sendEmail() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheet ID');       
  /// The ID of the data spreadshfeet   

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets(); // gets all sheets
  var startRow = 3;  // Third row of data to process
  var numRows = 40;   // Number of rows to process

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 10, numRows, 50); // Start row 3 column 10, and stop row 40, column 50

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  //Browser.msgBox(data)

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];

    if (dataRange.getValues() <= .60); {
      var emailAddress = "my email";  
      var message = row[2];       // Second column
      var subject = "ALERT - Assessment score below 60% inputted.";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      // Browser.msgBox(emailAddress)
    }
  }
}
```

```
function emailAlert(e) {
var range = e.range;
if (range.getColumn() >= 10) { // Only check column I and up
    var editedSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var editedRow = range.getRow();
    var value = range.getValue();
    if (value !== 'undefined') {
        if (value < 0.6) {
            var studentData = editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, 9).getValues();
            Logger.log(
                'StudentId: ' + studentData[0][0] +
                '\n Name: ' + studentData[0][1] +
                '\n HR: ' + studentData[0][2] +
                '\n Teacher: ' + studentData[0][3] +
                '\n Grade: ' + studentData[0][4] +
                '\n Race: ' + studentData[0][5] +
                '\n G: ' + studentData[0][6] +
                '\n Ed: ' + studentData[0][7] +
                '\n AVG: ' + studentData[0][8]);
            var emailAddress = "brandon.mause@sleschool.org";  
            var message = Test    
            var subject = "ALERT - Assessment score below 60% inputted.";
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
            // Send email..          
        }
    }
}
```

}

I added the new code above with the installable trigger active.  I still can't get the email function to work properly.  Any Ideas?
Thanks...

Comment: It might be better to not to work with onEdit trigger but rather to put this value in another column. You could set a timing trigger to work on the sheet and email only the 'new' entries.

Comment: Thanks Ido, I like the timing trigger idea.  How do I set it up to only evaluate the 'new' entries to make sure that they are < 60%?  Thanks again...

Comment: The best way to indicate new entries is to use a status column if it has been processed before.   So check the row only If status is "".   If you want you can even hide the column

Comment: So it sounds like the best way to do what I'm looking to do is to have a timing trigger that checks the sheet daily (thx Ido & Bjorn).  And to have it check a row only if the status is " ".  Being that I can't really edit the sheets that I made for teachers now.  Is there a way to use this "check row only if status is" features using the sheets set-up now?  I edited my original post with a link to an example data sheet like the one we use.  Could I set it up to look for data in row 1?  If there is data added to row 1, to then check the data in that column for any values less than 60%. thx guys

Comment: @BrandonMause  I would recommend to put a break points in your code, and try to debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your problem can be solved using the `onEdit` trigger. However, since you want to send an email you'll need to add the trigger manually because the function requires authorization to send emails.

Try this:

```
  function assessmentOnEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range;

    if (range.getColumn() >= 10) { // Only check column I and up
        var editedSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
        var editedRow = range.getRow();
        var value = range.getValue();
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            if (value < 0.6) {
                var studentData = editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, 9).getValues();
                var message = 'Assessment score: ' + Math.round((value * 100) * 10) / 10 + ' %' +
                    '\nStudentId: ' + studentData[0][0] +
                    '\nName: ' + studentData[0][1] +
                    '\nHR: ' + studentData[0][2] +
                    '\nTeacher: ' + studentData[0][3] +
                    '\nGrade: ' + studentData[0][4] +
                    '\nRace: ' + studentData[0][5] +
                    '\nG: ' + studentData[0][6] +
                    '\nEd: ' + studentData[0][7] +
                    '\nAVG: ' + Math.round((studentData[0][8] * 100) * 10) / 10 + ' %';

                var emailAddress = 'john.doe@example.com';
                var subject = 'ALERT - Assessment score below 60% inputted.';
                MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Check the google referance pages for more info on triggers: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

**EDIT**

Since you want to use `IMPORTRANGE` the `onEdit` trigger will not fire. Try using the function below and use this function with `onChange` instead of `onEdit`.

```
function assessmentOnChange(e) {

  var editedSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var propertyKey = 'currentColumn';
  var currentColumn = scriptProperties.getProperty(propertyKey);

  if (currentColumn === null) {
    currentColumn = 14; //Fisrt Empty column is N
  }

  var table = editedSheet.getRange(3, Number(currentColumn), editedSheet.getLastRow(), editedSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(),
      rowNumber = 3,
      valuesToProcess = [];

  table.forEach(function(row) {
    var column = 0;
    row.forEach(function(cell) {
      if (typeof cell === 'number') {
        valuesToProcess.push({
          value: cell,
          row: rowNumber,
          column: Number(currentColumn) + column
        })
      }
      column++;
    });
    rowNumber++;
  });

  var maxColumn = Number(currentColumn);
  for (var i in valuesToProcess) {
    assessmentOnEdit({
      source: e.source,
      range: {
        getRow: function() {
          return valuesToProcess[i].row
        },
        getValue: function() {
          return valuesToProcess[i].value
        },
        getColumn: function() {
          return valuesToProcess[i].column
        }
      }
    });

    if (valuesToProcess[i].column > maxColumn) {
      maxColumn = valuesToProcess[i].column;
    }
  }

  scriptProperties.setProperty(propertyKey, maxColumn + 1);
}
```

Comment: I ill give this a try.  I am always blown away by the skill level of the members on this site.  Thank you so much rckrd.  I really appreciate you taking time to try and help me out.

Comment: Okay, I've been reading up on triggers, messing with the script from rckrd above, and I'm stuck.  I know that with the onedit() trigger, this script can't be tested in the code editor.  I'm just not sure how to actually get it to run on my spread sheet.  I'm used to using  .openbyId which obviously goes out and open the spreadsheet and starts the function.  Is there anything that I need to add to this script to get it to work?  I'm confused as to what Im supposed to do in the editor now.  I know that these are all beginner questions, Sorry guys. I'm totally addicted now & trying to learn.  Thx

Comment: `onEdit()` trigger runs automatically when a user changes the value of any cell in a spreadsheet. If you paste the code in my answer above into your example spreadsheets script editor and save, this code will run every time a user edits a cell (on any sheet in this spreadsheet). You can test this by editing any cell, for example, enter "10%" in to cell "N5". Then go to the script editor and view the log (click on: "View --> Logs" in the menybar), in the log you should see the output of `Logger.log('StudentId: ' + studentData[0][0] + ....)` . Hope you get it working!

Comment: Okay, SO eventually I found a comment somewhere which said that onEdit() functions have limitations and that I needed to use an installable trigger.  So I renamed the function and set up the installable trigger to onEdit in (Resources > All your triggers > Add new trigger).  The script still isnt sending anything and I'm asssuming it's because of the syntax of my (rookie)code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am updating the code above to show my changes and  I am also trying to add in the log/email information the cell value that was below 60%.  Thx  Brandon

Comment: Yeah, I was just about comment on the restrictions for the standard trigger. I've updated my answer above, it sends the info from the spreadsheet if the supplied value is < 60%.

Comment: "rckrd" I cannot thank you enough!.  This script seems to work perfectly!  I really with that there was a donate button next to the profile names because I would send a couple your way for sure.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out.  I really appreciate it. Brandon

Comment: Come to find out the script works perfectly.  But since the cells are updated from a IMPORTRANGE function it doesn't trigger the onedit().  Any ideas?  I could switcb the trigger from an onEdit to a timed trigger, but then it will return all values < 60% every time.  Darn....so close.

Comment: What about adding a script that monitors the length of columns in the sheet, keeps the value somewhere (in script properties for example) and calls the assessmentOnEdit function if a column has been added?  I think that similar code is explained in the answer here.  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164736/trigger-onedit-with-a-programmatic-edit)  Im not really sure how change rows to columns and how to add it to my script.  But I'm looking into it.

Comment: Requirement changes are evil ;) A timed trigger will definitely work, but you'll need some way of knowing which values have been processed. I would use a script property, like you suggested, increment the column id each time the tigger runs. If a timed trigger is not suitable, I do think the `onChange` tigger runs when `IMPORTRANGE` is used.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Do you think that it would be easier for me to add an extra row at the top of the data sheet, and use this row to designate the rows that have been scanned and e-mailed?  I could have it running on a timing trigger so the IMPORTRANGE would still work.  Thoughts?

Comment: I created another post in an effort to get this thing working using a timing trigger and a column that has Sent if emails have been sent for it.  It wont send anything though, I bet you would know why...check it out if you want and Happy Holidays! [other post] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583046/gas-to-scan-a-sheet-look-for-values-and-send-e-mail-wont-do-anything-thought)

Comment: So, this was a fun problem so i wrote another function that you can use with `onChange`. Check my edited answer above. I haven't tested it thoroughly, but it seems to get the job done. Happy holidays!

Comment: at a Christmas party now,  I'll try it out when I get home... If I works (which I would assume it does because of your previous code) I'll be forever in your debt.  :)  thanks man,  you rock.   Happy Holidays!

Comment: Wow, cool looking code above.  How do I get this new edited code to run the email message portion of the script?  DO I add it to the end or something?  Thanks again man.

Comment: `assessmentOnChange` calls `assessmentOnEdit` (as you can see in the loop that loops through `valuesToProcess` ) so you'll still need `assessmentOnEdit` in your script.

Comment: Thanks man, I added the assessmentOnChange() and have a onchange trigger set up on it and I still have the assessmentOnEdit() on the script.  But it doesn't do anything when the data sheet is edit with <60% like it used to.  Being that assessmentOnEdit() is being called by assessmentOnChange(), I dont need any triggers set up for assessmentOnEdit() right?  The only trigger I have set up is for assessmentOnCHange() hmmmmmmmm.....