# Setting up an onEdit() installable trigger to recognize edits from IMPORTRANGE data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

"Rckrd" so kindly/skillfully helped me with the first script below that looks for data below 60% in a spreadsheet and sends an e-mail with info about the data.(Which works awesome!) This script is set up to run on an installable onEdit trigger and works great if I manually go into the spread sheet and change the cell values.

It does not work with our data system however, because our system uses `IMPORTRANGE` to populate the columns with data from other spreadsheets. Now it is my understanding that onEdit needs manual entries in order to fire.  Would it be possible to add the second script (below) that monitors the length of columns in the sheet, keeps the value somewhere (in script properties for example) and calls the `assessmentOnEdit()` function if a column of data has been added? I think that similar code is explained in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14164736/trigger-onedit-with-a-programmatic-edit).  I'm not even sure if this is a possibility to implement with my first code above or if it is the best way to get the onEdit to recognize the IMPORTRANGE added data.
Thanks so much for any help you can give and happy holidays!
Brandon

Here is the link to the original post that he helped me with. [Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466658/trying-to-make-a-script-that-scans-a-google-sheet-and-emails-if-values-are-below)

```js
  function assessmentOnEdit(e) {
    var range = e.range;

    if (range.getColumn() >= 10) { // Only check column I and up
        var editedSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
        var editedRow = range.getRow();
        var value = range.getValue();
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            if (value < 0.6) {
                var studentData = editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, 9).getValues();
                var message = 'Assessment score: ' + Math.round((value * 100) * 10) / 10 + ' %' +
                    '\nStudentId: ' + studentData[0][0] +
                    '\nName: ' + studentData[0][3] +
                    '\nHR: ' + studentData[0][2] +
                    '\nTeacher: ' + studentData[0][3] +
                    '\nGrade: ' + studentData[0][4] +
                    '\nRace: ' + studentData[0][5] +
                    '\nG: ' + studentData[0][6] +
                    '\nEd: ' + studentData[0][7] +
                    '\nAVG: ' + Math.round((studentData[0][8] * 100) * 10) / 10 + ' %';

                var emailAddress = 'john.doe@example.com';
                var subject = 'ALERT - Assessment score below 60% inputted.';
                MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```js
function lookatsheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID');// the ID of the SS you want to look at
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[1];// Second Sheet
  var lastcolumn = sh.getLastColumn() -2;// Get the last column that was inputted (minus the 2 top header rows, not sure if this is right)
  var formertest = ScriptProperties.getProperty('lastTest');// recover the value from the last test (will need to get called once to initiate a valid value)
  if (formertest < lastcolumn){
    sheetWasEdited(lastcolumn);// call your function with lastRow as parameter
    ScriptProperties.setProperties({'lastTest': lastcolumn}, true);   // store for next time
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your usecase is to send emails for data below 60% in the Spreadsheet(A), where the the sheet gets updated from a ImportRange from different Spreadsheet(B) all the time, instead of onEdit(e), you can simply edit your `lookatsheet()` function to get the new range of values from the Spreadsheet(A) in a below way:

```
    function lookatsheet(){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Spreadsheet ID');// the ID of the SS you want to look at
      var sh = ss.getSheets()[1];// Second Sheet
      var lastcolumn = sh.getLastColumn() -2;// Get the last column that was inputted (minus the 2 top header rows, not sure if this is right)
      var formertest = ScriptProperties.getProperty('lastTest');// recover the value from the last test (will need to get called once to initiate a valid value)
      if (formertest < lastcolumn){
        sheetWasEdited(lastcolumn);// call your function with lastRow as parameter
        ScriptProperties.setProperties({'lastTest': lastcolumn}, true);   // store for next time

// range would be the new range from the Sheet.

if (range.getColumn() >= 10) { // Only check column I and up
        var editedSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
        var editedRow = range.getRow();
        var value = range.getValue();
        if (typeof value === 'number') {
            if (value < 0.6) {
                var studentData = editedSheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, 9).getValues();
                var message = 'Assessment score: ' + Math.round((value * 100) * 10) / 10 + ' %' +
                    '\nStudentId: ' + studentData[0][0] +
                    '\nName: ' + studentData[0][3] +
                    '\nHR: ' + studentData[0][2] +
                    '\nTeacher: ' + studentData[0][3] +
                    '\nGrade: ' + studentData[0][4] +
                    '\nRace: ' + studentData[0][5] +
                    '\nG: ' + studentData[0][6] +
                    '\nEd: ' + studentData[0][7] +
                    '\nAVG: ' + Math.round((studentData[0][8] * 100) * 10) / 10 + ' %';

                var emailAddress = 'john.doe@example.com';
                var subject = 'ALERT - Assessment score below 60% inputted.';
                MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
            }
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Hope that helps!