# GAS to scan a sheet, look for values, and send e-mail wont do anything...thoughts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Basically my script is supposed to:

1. Open a certain sheet
2. check a certain range of data for values below 60%
3. once it finds one, check the first row of that column to see if it says 'Sent'
4. If it doess, do nothing
5. If it doesn't, send jthe email message in the script with the value below 60% etc.
6. Then edit row one of that column with 'Sent'once it send messages for all of the values below 60% in that column. ( I haven't written this part yet.

It says it runs fine, but it doesn't send anything.  I wrote most of this code from scratch and I'm kind of a beginner, so I'm wondering if I have errors that are keeping it from working.  I am going to have this run on a timing trigger BTW.
If you would mind looking it over and giving me some feedback, I'd greatly appreciate it.  I added the code below.
Happy Holidays!
Brandon

```js
   function sendEmail() { 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1CvK-ALbc-_GZwX4pqadBb67AVAou6euk55OE1axfbAk');
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  // The first of the above spreadsheet
    var range = sheet.getRange(3, 10, 40, 40); // Get 2D range (Starting Row (3) ,Starting Column (J), # Rows (40),# Colmuns (40))
    var value = range.getValue(); // get values of all cells in that range
        if (value < 0.6) {  // if it it get values that are less than 60%
            var editedsheet = value.getsheet();  // get sheet that value < 60% is in
            var editedRow = value.getRow();  // get row that value < 60% is in
            var column = value.getColumn();  // get column that value < 60% is in
            var status = editedsheet.getRange(0, column).getValue() // check row 1 of that column and get value
            
            if (status != 'Sent') {  // if that value is sent, do nothing
                }
            else {  // if the value isnt sent then...
                   var studentData = editedsheet.getRange(editedRow, 1, 1, 9).getValues();  // email message details
                   var message = 'Assessment score: ' + Math.round((value * 100) * 10) / 10 + ' %' +
                      '\nStudentId: ' + studentData[0][0] +
                      '\nName: ' + studentData[0][1] +
                      '\nHR: ' + studentData[0][2] +
                      '\nTeacher: ' + studentData[0][3] +
                      '\nGrade: ' + studentData[0][4] +
                      '\nRace: ' + studentData[0][5] +
                      '\nG: ' + studentData[0][6] +
                      '\nEd: ' + studentData[0][7] +
                      '\nAVG: ' + Math.round((studentData[0][8] * 100) * 10) / 10 + ' %';

                var emailAddress = 'email address';  // email details
                var subject = 'ALERT - Assessment score below 60% inputted.';
                MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
           }
       }
   }
```

Here is a link to an example spreadsheet like the one I'm using.
[Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CvK-ALbc-_GZwX4pqadBb67AVAou6euk55OE1axfbAk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code. E.g. use .getValues() instead of .getValue() if you want to get the values of the range. Also you will have to loop through the values that are returned.
I think your code should look something like this:
NOTE: untested code !

```
function assessmentAlert() {
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()
.forEach( function (s) {
var val = s.getDataRange().getValues();
//check to see if correct cells where found ==> check the log when the script finishes
var count = 0;
//start looping through the values, first loop = rows, second loop = columns
for (var i = 0, ilen = val.length; i < ilen; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, jlen = val[0].length; j < jlen; j++) {
      //conditions: column > 8, row > 2, value should be numeric and < 0.6 and the headerrow should not have 'Sent'
        if (j > 8 && i >2 && !isNaN(parseFloat(val[i][j])) && val[i][j] < 0.6 && val[0][j] != 'Sent') {
            count += 1
           //if all conditions are met, send the email             
            var message = 'Assessment score: ' + Math.round((val[i][j] * 100) * 10) / 10 + ' %' +
                '\nStudentId: ' + val[i][0] +
                '\nName: ' + val[i][1] +
                '\nHR: ' + val[i][2] +
                '\nTeacher: ' + val[i][3] +
                '\nGrade: ' + val[i][4] +
                '\nRace: ' + val[i][5] +
                '\nG: ' + val[i][6] +
                '\nEd: ' + val[i][7] +
                '\nAVG: ' + Math.round((val[i][8] * 100) * 10) / 10 + ' %';
            var emailAddress = 'email@email.com'; // email details
            var subject = 'ALERT - Assessment score below 60% inputted.';
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
            s.getRange(1, j+1).setValue('Sent').setFontColor('Red');
        }
    }
}
Logger.log('number of values found:' + count);
});
}
```

NOTE: the above code is untested. So I'll suggest you comment out the line MailApp.sendEmail and run the code and check the logger if the number of values found is correct.
I hope this helps ?

Comment: How can I get this script to loop through all of the sheets in the spreadsheet?  My spreadsheet has about 30 identical sheets in it with data for each teacher.  This script seems to work great though!  Thank you so much!  Brandon

Comment: Brandon, I've edited the code so that it now loops through all sheets. If you have lots of sheets, I only hope that the script finishes within the maximum allowed execution time of 6 minutes. Good luck.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your check for 'sent' is looking at a `getRange(0,column)`. While the array it returns starts at 0, you should specify row 1 as `getRange(1,column)`